# Behavior of introductory price for IAP on pre-iOS 11.2 devices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

If I set up an introductory price/free trial for a recurring subscription IAP, what happens when a user on e.g. an iOS 10 device initiates the IAP flow in my app? Obviously the `introductoryPrice` object won't be available on the `SKProduct`, but does Apple say whether the user will be charged the normal price or the introductory price?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For users below iOS 11.2 they won't see any introductory offer and will be charged the normal subscription price immediately.

Source: Testing this in production, couldn't find Apple docs on this either.